# Any method for checking data type in entry widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a game in which I take answer from players and match them with the correct ones. As I am using int data type I want the user only to enter int type of data. I want to limit user from entering any other data type but I am unable to do so. I also considered validate command but cannot understand it. Please help.

Here is my code's part where I want to do some additions..

```
def checkans(self,event):
    self.e.focus_set()
    if int(self.e.get())==self.ans:
            self.score+=10
```

Comment: I think my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647260/using-stringvar-data-as-a-list/41649219#41649219) could help you with the entry validation.

Comment: can you pls explain your other program to me?

Comment: I am using .isdigit but sometimes it is giving me questions having negative answers and there I am having an error.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647260/using-stringvar-data-as-a-list/41649219#41649219) is probably the answer to what you actually want (as pointed out in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379934/any-method-for-checking-data-type-in-entry-widget#comment89737761_51379934) by [j_4321](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6415268/j-4321)), it may be worthwhile to know how the `Entry` widget actually works.

The type of data returned by an `Entry` using the `.get()` method always returns the value as a `str`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)

entry.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Check Data Type", command=lambda: print(type(entry.get()))).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

You can, however, check whether the `str` represents a different type using a series of `try except`'s (although this is messy):

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root)

entry.pack()

def check(entry):
    try: 
        str(entry.get())
        print(True)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)
    try: 
        int(entry.get())
        print(True)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)
    try: 
        float(entry.get())
        print(True)
    except ValueError:
        print(False)

tk.Button(root, text="Check Data Type", command=lambda: check(entry)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```